# How to get user from on_remove_reaction?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord

I am attempting to create a discord bot, in one of its commands I first create an embed and send it to the channel using `ctx`. I add an emoji to said embed and then what I want to do is to listen to the emojis and specifically the people reacting on them.

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
.
.
.
def check(reaction, user):
      return str(reaction.emoji) == emoji_yes and client.user != user

while True:
      reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

This works like a charm, I can get a hold of the user and also update the embed with the names of the users that reacted.

What I would like now is to add or implement something in the same style, but for a user removing their reaction so I can update the embed again and remove their name if it was added previously.

`reaction, user = await client.wait_for('on_reaction_remove', check=check)`

I tried with this but couldn't get it to work, and since I am trying to achieve this in a command and not an event, on_raw_reaction_event is out of the picture as far as I've understood.

Any idea on how to achieve 'on_reaction_remove'?

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be a lost cause, after trying to implement `on_reaction_remove` which according to the documentation should work, I decided that I had to approach this with a workaround. Once the bot is functioning, I might go back and try to figure out why it went wrong.

Since I want this functionality inside of my command and not in a separate event, `on_raw_reaction_remove` is not an option for this case.

But instead of trying to figure out how to listen to every event on when a user adds or removes their reaction, what I do is listen to the list of users that have reacted to the emoji added to my embed.

```
getmsg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(embed_message.id)
users = await getmsg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
```

I then handle users in different ways, one is creating a string that always lists all of the users that have reacted in the embed itself.

If anyone still knows how to solve `on_reaction_remove`, feel free to add. Otherwise I hope this might help anyone in my situation for now.